# Bugzilla automated email settings file

Tags: bugzilla

Several months ago I've successfully installed `bugzilla` on local test server. Now, I wanted to change my credentials email in `bugzilla` and I've got following email:

> Bugzilla has received a request to change the email address for the
>   account user@test.com to your address.
>
> To confirm the change, visit the following link:
>
> http://84.21.236.183/bugzilla/token.cgi?t=8aiQF72AFE&a=cfmem
>
> If you are not the person who made this request, or you wish to cancel
>   this request, visit the following link:
>
> http://84.21.236.183/bugzilla/token.cgi?t=8aiQF72AFE&a=cxlem
>
> If you do nothing, the request will lapse after 3 days (on October 10,
>   2015 at 15:46 CEST).

The problem is, that I've moved server to new location and got new internet provider, which gave me new static IP address, so `84.21.236.183` is no longer valid. Where do I setup this IP in `bugzilla` settings files so it will point to new IP address?

Comment: Maybe `urlBase` in  `/bugzilla/editparams.cgi`?

Comment: @muru I have no `urlBase` in `/var/www/html/bugzilla`, the installation directory, I've `grep`ed it with ` sudo grep -r urlBase *`.

Comment: I meant go to `http://X.y.z.w/bugzilla/editparams.cgi` in your browser. In the installation directory, it's likely in `data/params.json` or similarly named file.

Comment: @muru this time I've `grep`ed with command `sudo grep -r urlbase *|grep params` and the right file is `data/params`, can you please upgrade your helpful comment into answer so I can upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try modifying the `urlBase` parameter. Online, this can be done by logging in to Bugzilla and heading to `/editparams.cgi`, where it's the first parameter in the *Required Settings* category (`http://x.y/bugzilla/editparams.cgi?section=core#urlbase_desc`, for example).

Offline, the parameter is saved in a file in `data/`, named `params` in older installations and `params.json` in newer versions (I've seen `params.json` since 4.8.8, IIRC).